# Prove that if $m \mid n$ then the function $\pi_{m,n}$ is well defined.

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, modular-arithmetic

Started out writing this question not knowing where to start but in the process of writing it out I think I *may* have worked something out. Would appreciate any feedback and critique as to whether this is the correct logic and overall procedure for the solution (this is not my proof as it's far too disjointed and not written as such, yet.) Thank you!

---

**Definitions**

The function $\pi_{m,n}: \mathbb{Z_n} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z_m}$ is defined to be $\pi_{m,n}([a]_n) = [a]_m$. So, this function takes some element of the congruence class $[a]$ modulo $n$ to the same congruence class $[a]$ modulo $m$.

---

**What we need to show**

The question is asking us to show that the above function is well-defined, i.e.,

- $[a]_n = [b]_n$ for $[a],[b] \in \mathbb{Z_n}$ implies that $\pi_{m,n}([a]_n) = \pi_{m,n}([b]_n) = [a]_m = [b]_m$ for $[a],[b] \in \mathbb{Z_m}$

---

**My thought process**

So I first started out by listing things that I know that are implied by what we are given. Namely:

1. $m \mid n \rightarrow n = km, k \in \mathbb{Z}$
2. Since $n = km$ is a multiple of $m$ that means that $[a]_n \subset [a]_m$

   - Take $a = 3, n = 8$ and $ m = 4$ then we have:

     - $[3]_8 = \{..., -13,-5,3,11,19,...\}$
     - $[3]_4 = \{...,-13,-9,-5,-1,3,7,11,15,19,...\}$
   - Written generally:

     - $[a]_n = [a]_{mk} = \{..., a + (-2)km, a + (-1)km, a, a + (1)km, a + (2)km,...\}$
     - $[a]_m = \{..., a + (-2)m, a + (-1)m, a, a + (1)m, a + (2)m,...\}$
   - So we see that if $a \in [a]_n$ then $a \in [a]_m$. Hence $[a]_n \subset [a]_m$.

Now I know that the 'trick' of this problem is to show that it doesn't matter which representative we choose for $[a]_n$ that we get the same congruence class (and hence set) regardless of which $a$ we choose, provided $a \in [a]_n$ so that if we choose $2$ representatives $a,b \in [a]_n$ then we get the same $2$ representatives of that same congruence class modulo $m, [a]_m$ after we pass it through the function $\pi_{m,n}$. So, it seems there are $2$ parts to this problem:

1. To show that the choice of representative doesn't matter. How exactly would I do this? Would it be as simple as just stating that provided $a,b \in  [a]_n$ then $[a]_n = [b]_n$ necessarily by definition of congruence class?

   - Also, as an aside, should I refrain from using $a$ as the representative of the congruence class if I'm then going to use $a$ and $b$ as $2$ separate representatives? I know it wouldn't necessarily invalidate the point, but would it be read easier and cleaner if I were to say instead "provided $a,b \in [c]_n$ then... "?
2. Then to show that $m \mid n$ implies that $\pi_{m,n}$ is well defined. For this would it come down to what I said before about how $m \mid n$ implies that $[a]_n \subset [a]_m$? Since if $a \in [a]_n$ then $a \in [a]_m$ and also $b \in [a]_n$ implies $b \in [a]_m$, and since $a,b \in [a]_m $ that implies $[a]_m = [b]_m$? Does that make sense? Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 1):

Your observations, examples, musings are all (mostly) good. There are some minor errors, e.g. in your initial definition, you write

> So, this function takes some element of the congruence class $[a]$
> modulo $n$ to the same congruence class $[a]$ modulo $m$.

The equivalence classes are not *the same*, as they are the classes of different equivalence relations. They are equivalence classes of the same representative $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ in those equivalence relations.

---

But this is **way too verbose** for a proof. The crucial mathematical deductions are lost in a sea of other things. The proof can be written far more succinctly, as follows:
\begin{align} 
[a]_n = [b]_n 
&\implies a \equiv b \bmod{n} \\
&\implies n \mid (a-b) \\
&\implies m \mid (a-b) \tag{*}\\
&\implies a \equiv b \bmod{m} \\
&\implies [a]_m = [b]_m \\
&\implies \pi_{m,n}([a]_n) = \pi_{m,n}([b]_n)
\end{align}

(*) **Lemma:** If $m \mid n$ and $n \mid k$, then $m \mid k$.

*Prove this if you haven’t already.*